# static ip disable external internet

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, static-ip

I have just tried to set static ip on my raspbian.

I have added those line into `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface INTERFACENAME(ETH0/WLAN0)
static ip_address=192.168.101.46/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

And then I've reboot the raspberry.

when the system start I can login via SSH to the new local ip, but when I try to ping google there is no response. 
I have tried to put Google DNS `8.8.8.8` but I have not recevied any respond.

Thanks.

BTW - I've seen similar questions over here but I still unable to fix the problem.

Comment: I have disabled it, and restart. same same :( I get: ping: google.co.il: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: The given IPv4 address `192.168.101.46` in combination with the mask bit `24` results in a CIDR address range of `192.168.101.0 - 192.168.101.255`. Nice tool for this: [CIDR Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php).

Answer (score 4):

If:

```
static ip_address=192.168.101.46/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
```

Your router subnet is incorrect for your device because the subnet mask says your devices network is 192.168.101 and your router network is 192.168.1.

HTH

Comment: I get what you are saying but I have also tried 192.168.1.99 as well.

Comment: 192.168.1.99 for what?

Comment: on static ip_address of course..

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt you have an interface `INTERFACENAME(ETH0/WLAN0)` - there are other obvious errors.

If you absolutely **MUST** set a static address [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)
explains how to do it.

I still fail to understand why so many Pi users **WANT** to set a static IP address, particularly when they seem to have little understanding of networking.

Comment: by writing `INTERFACENAME(ETH0/WLAN0)` I have meant that the interfacename should be eth0 or wlan0 and its still need to be the same as the interface himself.

Answer (score 0):

@itzikb I think you put wrong address meanwhile in changing IP address process. as @ghost said, your router subnet is incorrect for your device. You have to change your configuration. look at this [link](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update) might give you answer of your solution.

Comment: fyi: we have verified the IP addresses on chat and I can confirm: SSH from PC to RPi at 192.168.101.46 is working, the routers webinterface is available at 192.168.1.1